# android 3.0+ action bar keep background when styling

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, titlebar

I'm developing an App for Android 3.0+ and I want to personalize the action bar by removing the title, which I can accomplish, my problem is that I also lose the background on the action bar, I would just like to remove the title and keep the remaining style. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarNoTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarNoTitle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    </style>

    </resources>
```

I'd prefer not to change the Activity code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which theme are you using? That is probably defined in `values-v11` or `values-v14`. If `Theme.Holo.Light` you have to change the `actionBarStyle`'s parent style to `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid`.

```
<style name="ActionBarNoTitle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but that requires minSDK 14, I'd prefer 11 if possible.

Comment: For `v11`, it is `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer, although the problem is that `v11` doesn't support dark action bar, which I didn't know, my bad there and considering that only 0.1% of the devices run Honeycomb, I'll just change the minsdk to 14. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this,

define this in your theme.xml file,

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

define this in your style.xml file,

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
        <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It does work, I've tried this solution, but seems a little dirty, considering there's a cleaner way to do it. It also makes use of the theme from api 11. Thanks anyway :)